# tsc - doesn't compile alias paths

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I have typescript and uses the aliases.
Here is part of tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./src",
   ...
},
```

By setting the base url, I can change

```
import User from "src/models/User.model.ts"
```

to

```
import User from "models/User.model.ts"
```

The problem is that tsc compiles src folder to dist folder, so User import path should be changed to the relative path something like this:

```
"../models/User.model.js"
```

But it doesn't change, so I get the following error:

```
"models/User.model.js" not found
```

I searched for the answer, but no luck.

Answer (score 68):

TSC compiler alone **can't resolve** the alias paths. So in order to make it work you will be required to install additional dev package

```
npm install --save-dev tsc-alias
```

[tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) is for replacing alias paths with relative paths after typescript compilation of tsc compiler because the compiler alone can't resolve the alias paths

After that you need to **modify your build command** in your **package.json** file to

```
"build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
```

Running `npm run build` should work after that and the code should be compiled correctly to javascript

If you want to enable also **hot reloading** you will be required to install one more dev package

```
npm install --save-dev concurrently
```

[concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) is for runing multiple commands concurrently

After that you will need to **add 1 new script** inside your **package.json** file

```
"build:watch": "concurrently --kill-others \"tsc -w\" \"tsc-alias -w\"",
```

Running `npm run build:watch` should work after that and the code should be compiled correctly to javascript with hot reload functionality

**Please Note:**  I am using this versions of the packages

```
"tsc-alias": "^1.5.0",
"typescript": "^4.5.5",
"concurrently": "^7.0.0",
```

Older or newer versions might introduce some issues with compiling the code

Comment: Have been searching around for an hour, finally find a solution that works! Thanks so much!

Comment: this trick did it for me

Comment: this is safe my life

Comment: In the case of javascript without an extension in its `import` statement, apply the `--resolve-full-paths` parameter to the `tsc-alias`.

Comment: Good job man :))

Answer (score 16):

There's a long discussion in typescript issues about this, and I can't seem find better solution than this.

**Development**

```
npm i -save-dev tsconfig-paths/register
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    },   
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  dev: "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"
}
```

**Build**

```
npm i -save-d ttypescript @zerollup/ts-transform-paths
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
          "transform": "@zerollup/ts-transform-paths",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  build: "ttsc -P ./tsconfig.json"
}
```

Comment: I tried this exact setup, and received the following error when building: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'impliedNodeFormat')`.

Comment: Error is due to the fact that @zerollup/ts-transform-paths is broken for TypeScript 4.5+: https://github.com/zerkalica/zerollup/issues/37

Comment: I have the same issue on typescript 4.3.5

Answer (score 5):

[ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript)

[typescript-transform-paths](https://github.com/LeDDGroup/typescript-transform-paths)

[babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

`package.json` part

```
"build": "ttsc && babel dist -d dist",
```

`ttsc` is not a mistake, it's a plugin over typescript config for more complex transpiling

`tsconfig.json` part

```
"outDir": "dist",
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
    "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
    ],
    "$/*": [
        "./tests/unit/*"
    ]
},
"plugins": [
    {
        "transform": "typescript-transform-paths",
        "afterDeclarations": true
    }
],
```

`.babelrc` whole content

```
{
  "compact": false,
  "retainLines": true,
  "minified": false,
  "inputSourceMap": false,
  "sourceMaps": false,
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./dist"],
        "alias": {
          "@": "./dist"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Explain what these repositories are for?

Comment: I think README files of those repo-s will help you)

Comment: This looks like it'd work just fine! Unfortunately, `typescript-transform-paths` doesn't work in TS 4.0: https://github.com/LeDDGroup/typescript-transform-paths/issues/68

Comment: The best alternative I've found so far is this: https://github.com/joonhocho/tscpaths

Comment: @SeizeTheDay the support for TS 4+ was introduced a week after your comment 

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that it is very simple to resolve.
As long as you define proper path within the `path` like this in file `tsconfig.json`

```js
"paths": {
   "@/*": ["./src/*"]
}
```

And not like this

```js
"baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./*"]
},
```

And build (transpile TS to JS) using the command `tsc && tsc-alias`.
It will work.
Also make sure that you install typescript to enable tsc and tsc-alias to enable tsc-alias command above. You can do that by
`npm i --save-dev typescript`
`npm i --save-dev tsc-alias`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I use:

- ttypescript
- @zerollup/ts-transform-paths
- tsc-watch

***How:***

**Installation** via npm:

```
npm install -D ttypescript @zerollup/ts-transform-paths tsc-watch
```

In **tsconfig.json** add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "@zerollup/ts-transform-paths",
        "exclude": ["*"]
      }
    ]
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

In **package.json** the scripts look like this:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "build": "ttsc",
    "watch": "tsc-watch --compiler ttypescript/bin/tsc --onSuccess 'npm start'",
    "watch-only": "ttsc -w",
    ...
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell the Node what the base url is with NODE_PATH environment variable so that it can resolve absolute paths:

```bash
NODE_PATH=dist/ node ./dist/index.js
```

Comment: is this all supposed to be assigned to `NODE_PATH` or was this supposed to be more than one cli entry? e.g.:

`$ NODE_PATH=dist/`
`$ node ./dist/index.js`

Also, is there a place this could be put in a config file or something? I suppose just as a preceding `package.json` script to run with the build script would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the dev dependencies you need `ts-node`, `tsconfig-paths` and `typescript-transform-paths` and typescript configuration

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "require": [
      "typescript-transform-paths/register",
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "plugins": [{"transform": "typescript-transform-paths"}]
  },
  ...
}
```