# How to get rid of relative import in Typescript + Node 18?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, absolute-path, relative-import, tsconfig-paths

I'm currently running a backend application in Typescript 5.2, which can be build to run as a Debian service on production with node 18 or directly run in a Docker container through nodemon.

Everywhere in my app you can find relative imports, sometimes short, sometimes very long:

```
import { Shortcut } from './Shortcut';
import { formatQuery } from '../../../../../../helpers/formatQuery';
```

And I would like to get rid of these imports.

---

My `package.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "toto",
  "version": "1.4.9",
  "description": "tata",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon --config ./node_modules/@titi/config/nodemon.json",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "29.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "3.0.1",
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.17.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.17"
  }
}
```

I use a custom `nodemon.json` which is:

```json
{
  "watch": ["src/", "*.json"],
  "ignore": [
    ".git",
    "public",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules",
    "src/**/*.test.*",
    "src/**/*.spec.*"
  ],
  "ext": "ts,js,json",
  "exec": "tsc -p tsconfig.json --incremental && node --trace-warnings --trace-uncaught build || exit 1"
}
```

and finally, my `tsconfig.json` file look like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../../../build",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": [
        "src/services/*"
      ],
      "@routes/*": [
        "src/routes/*"
      ],
      "@helpers/*": [
        "src/helpers/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "files": ["../../../src/index.ts"],
}
```

---

I **already** know a lot of solutions do exists, I already tried a lot of them but none worked, like:

- ### Setting the `baseUrl` property

No matter if I set it to `.` or `./src` in my `tsconfig.json`, I can't start my project and I keep getting this error:

```
import { formatQuery } from 'src/helpers';
```

> `src/services/toto.ts:5:29 - error TS2307`: Cannot find module 'src/helpers' or its corresponding type declarations.

- ### Adding `paths` properties to the `tsconfig.json`

Whenever I set a `paths` property, it's being ignored. For example:

```json
"@helpers/*": [ "src/helpers/*" ]
```

and import a function like this result to:

```
import { formatQuery } from '@helpers';
```

> `src/services/toto.ts:5:29 - error TS2307`: Cannot find module '@helpers' or its corresponding type declarations.

(and that even if I put `@helpers/formatQuery`, and even with a `BaseUrl` to `.`)

- ### using the `NODE_PATH` env variable

Since `BaseUrl` and `paths` properties change the compiled files (javascript), you can't expect JavaScript to know where is the BaseUrl, so I tried to use this env variable in my `nodemon.json`'s "exec" like:

```json
"exec": "tsc -p tsconfig.json --incremental && NODE_PATH=src node --trace-warnings --trace-uncaught build || exit 1"
```

- ### Changing my IDE settings (for both JS and TS)

I'm currently using VSCode, and I read somewhere that I needed to edit the `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` variable to `non-relative` (even if I'm not fond of this way, because it globally means new developers that will works on my project won't be abble to make it works if they don't set this property in their VSCode ?)

- ### Using new [SubPath pattern](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns)
- ### Adding a `jsconfig.json`

I tried to add a `jsconfig.json` file with `baseUrl` and `paths` property as put in the `tsconfig.json`, but it didn't worked.

---

**EDIT**: I just forget to tell that the file `src/helpers/index.ts` do exists, and for clarity sake I'm adding here it's content:

```
export * from './parseString';
export * from './formatQuery';
...
```

---

So what am I doing wrong ? is my architecture too complex to use non-relative imports ?

Comment: "And I would like to get rid of these imports" why? I mean, it's a perfectly valid question, but is this really a problem you need to solve? And if it is that pervasive, should your repo be a monorepo with separate packages that import each other? Because while that's a more heavyweight solution than your attempted use of various aliasing mechanisms, the fact that your relative paths are that long may be trying to tell you something about your code structuring...

Comment: @JaredSmith Actually, it's already a company monorepo with multiple app and packages. Is it a hindrance ? yeah, it's a personal point of view, even the slighest `../helpers.ts` trigger me, I would like to have path aliasing precisely for comprehension sake :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some little changes on `baseUrl` and `paths`:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@helpers/*": [ "./very/long/path/to/helpers/*" ],
}

...

import XXX from '@helpers/XXX'
```

On paths you don't need to add `src` because `baseUrl` is making paths to start from this folder. If you add it then `ts` will search for `/src/src/....` and this is not the case. Read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl).

After setting `paths` you need to use `tsc-alias` so `@helpers/XXX` will be correctly converted to the actual path of file after typescript build. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905194/9894625) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but yeah obviously I had an `index.ts` file in `src/helpers/` that only export all content such as `export * from './formatQuery';`.
But unfortunaly, adding a `rootDir` didn't solve the problem, it cause my nodemon to constantly restart my app without even letting it the time to finish to compile

Comment: Oh, sorry I've noticed now that `/helpers` folder is not at root of your project. In this case you need to adjust `paths` to where the folder is. E.g: `"@helpers/*": [ "./very/long/path/to/helpers/*" ]`. About `rootDir`, I don't think this option is the problem to make nodemon to restart (I couldn't find anything about this on google) but you can remove it, I've tested now and aliases works without this option. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Okay, after further investigations, I succeeded to make the `rootDir` work (with my pecullar installation it should've been `"rootDir": "../../../src"` like it's done in the `include` above, but it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Try updating `baseUrl` to same you did in `rootDir`: `./very/long/path/to/src`. Remember to adjust it based on where `tsconfig.json` file is.

Comment: Okay, it did works ! setting the `baseUrl` to `"../../../src"` successfully worked. I can now `yarn build`, but when `yarn start:dev` nodemon (so node) will complain with the following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'helpers/formatQuery'`. Maybe setting the `NODE_PATH` would be sufficient ?

Comment: Ohh I forgot, when you're using `paths` you must also use `tsc-alias` (you can add it as a dev dependency) when building `ts` files. This package will transpile `@helpers/xxx` to `../..etc../xxx` in the builded file. To build and transpile paths you need to run `tsc && tsc-alias` command. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905194/9894625)

Comment: Yeah, I know the principle, but why should I use `tsc-alias` ? shouldn't I use [`tsconfig-paths`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) which is the common reference ? (maybe more stable than `tsc-alias` for a professional use, for what I see ?)

Comment: I think both will work the same way... not sure because I only use `tsc-alias` as it's very simple, easy to use and works very well.